# How to import library from jitpack.io using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I tried following [these instructions](https://jitpack.io/#qiugang/EditTag/v1.2.3) so the related parts of my build.gradle (app) looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

compile 'com.github.qiugang:EditTag:v1.2.3'
```

but Android Studio still displays this error message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.github.qiugang:EditTag:v1.2.3.
     Required by:
         myapp-yeah:app:unspecified
```

Comment: Are you missing a `dependencies { }` section where you put the `compile`?

Comment: No, I just didn't paste it all here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You modified `buildscript`. The instructions show changing `allprojects`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

`buildscript` is used for Gradle plugins, and this library apparently is not a Gradle plugin.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now, also I followed the following suggestion from Android Studio:
 `add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-41:19 to override.`

Comment: As usual CommonsWare to the rescue!